# How to pass State with context Api react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

First I created a .js file and created context.

In app.js

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {
    const [ItemURL,setItemURL] = useState('URL')

    return (
        <ItemContext.Provider value={ItemURL}>
            ...
        </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

now I want to pass my `setItemURL` to my child component

So I tried.

```
export default const ItemsComponent = (props) => {
    const [URL, setURL] = useContext(ItemContext)
    return(
       <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => {
                    setURL(props.Json.Image)
                }}
            />
    )
}
```

but its not working and saying `setURL is not a function(in setURL(props.Json.Image)) ,setURL is 'R'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually pass the `setURL` function in the context value as well.

```
export default function App({ navigation }) {
  const [ItemURL, setItemURL] = useState('URL');

  const value = [ItemURL, setItemURL];

  return (
    <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>
      ...
    </ItemContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: please help me with how can I access it in other components?

Comment: @anonymousmind Does `const [URL, setURL] = useContext(ItemContext);` not work?  You may need to instead wrap the context values in an object versus array. Can you add how you declare your `ItemContext` to your question?

Comment: sorry for that I forgot to change  const [URL, setURL] = useContext(ItemContext); in other components.Now its working fine Thanks..